# Resume Data from URLSessionDownloadTask Always nil

Tags: swift3, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

i have an app which i need to download the file from the internet when i downloading the file it's work good but my problem is when i pressed pause button to pause the downloading for one minute or more i get nil from resume Data

the following my code :

```
@IBAction func startDownloading(_ sender: UIButton)
{     
    isDownload = true
    sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.main
    session = URLSession.init(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
    let url = URL(string: "www.example.com")
    downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url!)
    downloadTask.resume()
}
@IBAction func pause(_ sender: UIButton) 
{
    if downloadTask != nil && isDownload 
    {
        self.downloadTask!.cancel(byProducingResumeData: { (resumeData) in
                        // here is the nil from the resume data
                    })
        isDownload = false
        downloadTask = nil
        pasueBtnOutlet.setTitle("Resume", for: .normal)
    }
    if !isDownload && downloadData != nil 
    {
        downloadTask = session.downloadTask(withResumeData: downloadData as Data)
        downloadTask.resume()
        isDownload = true
        downloadData = nil
        pasueBtnOutlet.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
    }                    
}
```

please can help me

thanks for all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLSessionDownloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215610/nsurlsessiondownloadtask-cancelbyproducingresumedata-return-null)

Comment: This is dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215610/nsurlsessiondownloadtask-cancelbyproducingresumedata-return-null

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, you just need to init the `downloadData` with `resumeData` in closure

Make a property of `downloadData`

```
var downloadData:Data!
```

and then in your pause button action where you cancel the task, set the `downloadData` with `resumeData`

```
self.downloadTask!.cancel(byProducingResumeData: { (resumeData) in
        // here is the nil from the resume data

        // You have to set download data with resume data
        self.downloadData = resumeData
})
```

In order to check the progress and completion, implement these `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` delegates

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    print(Int(progress * 100))

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("Downloading done")
}
```

**NOTE:-** Try a valid downloadable url. For example
      http://www.star.uclan.ac.uk/news_and_events/news/2010020901/sdo_resolution_comparison.png

Its http, make sure to set Transport Security in Info.plist

Comment: the problem is resumeData is the nil from the closure you can try this and you will see it's nil i think have problem from the Apple

Comment: Your URL should be valid for downloading

Comment: What's your URL for downloading?

Comment: Please give the URL first

Comment: @HaiderAhmed Have you checked the URL on browser whether it is playing the song or downloading it for you

Comment: yes my friend i check and i can download the music and also in the app it is download it also but only when i pause the download i get the resumeData nil

Comment: Please provide the URL and I'll check that in my sample app. Because its working fine here. If everything goes well post the sample link